# Thread: signal SIGABRT - Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, swift3, storyboard

So this is my following code, its nearly the same as the first storyboard on this app and it works so its very confusing why it doesn't work this time.

```
protocol HomeModelCleanersDelegate{
    func itemsDownloaded(cleaners:[Cleaner])
}


class HomeModelCleaners: NSObject {
    
    var delegate:HomeModelCleanersDelegate?

    func getItems(){
        
        //Hit the web service url
        
        let serviceUrl =  "https://absolutecleandatabase.com/Cleaners.php"
        
        // Download the json data
        
        let url = URL(string: serviceUrl)
        
        if let url = url {
            
            // Create a URL session
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:
                                            {(data, response, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    // Succeded
                    
                    // Vall the parse json function on the data
                    self.parseJson(data:data!) // here it gets a signal SIGABRT error
                    
                }
                else{
                    // Error occurred
                }
                
            })
            
            // Start the task
            task.resume()
            
        }
        
        // Notify the view controller and pass the data back
    }
  
        func parseJson(data:Data){
            var clArray = [Cleaner]()
           
            
            //parse the data into the locations structs
            
            do {
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as! [Any]
            
            for jsonResult in jsonArray{
                let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String] // here it gets a signal SIGABRT error
                let cl = Cleaner(name: jsonDict["Name"]!, startingTime: jsonDict["Starting Time"]!, finishingTime: jsonDict["Finishing Time"]!,hours: jsonDict["Hours"]!, date: jsonDict["Date"]!)
                
                clArray.append(cl)
            }
                
                delegate!.itemsDownloaded(cleaners:clArray)
                
        }
        catch{
            print("Error")
       
        }            
    }
 }
```

I have the same code on my Main storyboard and it works perfectly fine with parsing the JSON data. I've also tried using '?' instead of '!' but Im not sure how to change the code in a way that '?' would work. I'm not sure what went wrong here since I'm still a beginner

Comment: If `jsonResult as! [String:String]` makes crash, then it means that `jsonResult` is not a `[String: String]`. Could it be a `[String: Any]`? Could you print the JSON? print("JSON: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)"))`?

Comment: Best solution is probably using Codable but with your current code you could try casting to [String:String?] or [String:Any] instead of [String:String]